# Mocked `lockf` ends up getting called twice when it should be called once

Tags: python, multithreading, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I'm writing a test to check my program's locking functionality.

For the first test I'm trying to assert if the `lockf` function is getting called only once, as the subsequent locking calls without releasing the lock would result in errors (which is what I want).

So, I have mocked the `lockf` function, and am asserting that it's getting called once.

But the `lockf` function ends up getting called twice when it should be called once, (it should error out the second time).

What am I doing wrong here? And how do I fix this?

My guess is that the `t1` thread finishes and releases the lock before `t2` locks it, so there are no errors and `lockf` ends up getting called twice.

## Code

### Test

```py
import logging
from argparse import Namespace
from threading import Thread
from unittest.mock import patch

import pytest

import pacstall.__main__


class TestLockingCommands:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("command", ["install", "remove", "upgrade", "repo"])
    def test_if_lock_is_called(self, command: str, monkeypatch: pytest.MonkeyPatch):
        logging.getLogger(__name__).setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        with patch("fcntl.lockf") as mock_lockf:
            t1 = Thread(
                target=pacstall.__main__.lock,
                args=(Namespace(command=command), logging.getLogger(__name__)),
            )
            t2 = Thread(
                target=pacstall.__main__.lock,
                args=(Namespace(command=command), logging.getLogger(__name__)),
            )
            t1.start()
            t2.start()
            t1.join()
            t2.join()
            mock_lockf.assert_called_once()
```

### Production code

```py
import fcntl
import sys
from argparse import Namespace
from asyncio import run
from getpass import getuser
from logging import Logger, getLogger
from time import sleep

from rich import print as rprint
from rich.traceback import install

from pacstall.api import logger
from pacstall.api.error_codes import ErrorCodes
from pacstall.cmds import download
from pacstall.parser import parse_arguments


def lock(args: Namespace, log: Logger) -> None:
    if args.command in ["install", "remove", "upgrade", "repo"]:
        lock_file = open("/var/lock/pacstall.lock", "w")
        while True:
            try:
                fcntl.lockf(lock_file, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
                log.debug("Lock acquired")
                break
            except OSError:
                log.warn("Pacstall is already running another instance")
                sleep(1)
```

### Test output

```py
========================================================= test session starts ==========================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.10, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /media/pop-os/SBASAK/code/pacstall, configfile: pyproject.toml
plugins: anyio-3.5.0
collected 4 items

tests/test_locking.py FFFF                                                                                                       [100%]

=============================================================== FAILURES ===============================================================
_________________________________________ TestLockingCommands.test_if_lock_is_called[install] __________________________________________

self = <tests.test_locking.TestLockingCommands object at 0x7f32944893a0>, command = 'install'
monkeypatch = <_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch object at 0x7f32944d7e50>

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("command", ["install", "remove", "upgrade", "repo"])
    def test_if_lock_is_called(self, command: str, monkeypatch: pytest.MonkeyPatch):
        logging.getLogger(__name__).setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        with patch("fcntl.lockf") as mock_lockf:
            t1 = Thread(
                target=pacstall.__main__.lock,
                args=(Namespace(command=command), logging.getLogger(__name__)),
            )
            t2 = Thread(
                target=pacstall.__main__.lock,
                args=(Namespace(command=command), logging.getLogger(__name__)),
            )
            t1.start()
            t2.start()
            t1.join()
            t2.join()
>           mock_lockf.assert_called_once()

tests/test_locking.py:50:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <MagicMock name='lockf' id='139855212529552'>

    def assert_called_once(self):
        """assert that the mock was called only once.
        """
        if not self.call_count == 1:
            msg = ("Expected '%s' to have been called once. Called %s times.%s"
                   % (self._mock_name or 'mock',
                      self.call_count,
                      self._calls_repr()))
>           raise AssertionError(msg)
E           AssertionError: Expected 'lockf' to have been called once. Called 2 times.
E           Calls: [call(<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/var/lock/pacstall.lock' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>, 6),
E            call(<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/var/lock/pacstall.lock' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>, 6)].

/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/mock.py:892: AssertionError
---------------------------------------------------------- Captured log call -----------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG    tests.test_locking:__main__.py:50 Lock acquired
DEBUG    tests.test_locking:__main__.py:50 Lock acquired
__________________________________________ TestLockingCommands.test_if_lock_is_called[remove] __________________________________________

self = <tests.test_locking.TestLockingCommands object at 0x7f329318f040>, command = 'remove'
monkeypatch = <_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch object at 0x7f329318f370>

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("command", ["install", "remove", "upgrade", "repo"])
    def test_if_lock_is_called(self, command: str, monkeypatch: pytest.MonkeyPatch):
        logging.getLogger(__name__).setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        with patch("fcntl.lockf") as mock_lockf:
            t1 = Thread(
                target=pacstall.__main__.lock,
                args=(Namespace(command=command), logging.getLogger(__name__)),
            )
            t2 = Thread(
                target=pacstall.__main__.lock,
                args=(Namespace(command=command), logging.getLogger(__name__)),
            )
            t1.start()
            t2.start()
            t1.join()
            t2.join()
>           mock_lockf.assert_called_once()

tests/test_locking.py:50:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <MagicMock name='lockf' id='139855192978336'>

    def assert_called_once(self):
        """assert that the mock was called only once.
        """
        if not self.call_count == 1:
            msg = ("Expected '%s' to have been called once. Called %s times.%s"
                   % (self._mock_name or 'mock',
                      self.call_count,
                      self._calls_repr()))
>           raise AssertionError(msg)
E           AssertionError: Expected 'lockf' to have been called once. Called 2 times.
E           Calls: [call(<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/var/lock/pacstall.lock' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>, 6),
E            call(<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/var/lock/pacstall.lock' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>, 6)].

/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/mock.py:892: AssertionError
---------------------------------------------------------- Captured log call -----------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG    tests.test_locking:__main__.py:50 Lock acquired
DEBUG    tests.test_locking:__main__.py:50 Lock acquired
_________________________________________ TestLockingCommands.test_if_lock_is_called[upgrade] __________________________________________

self = <tests.test_locking.TestLockingCommands object at 0x7f329316f4c0>, command = 'upgrade'
monkeypatch = <_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch object at 0x7f329316f310>

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("command", ["install", "remove", "upgrade", "repo"])
    def test_if_lock_is_called(self, command: str, monkeypatch: pytest.MonkeyPatch):
        logging.getLogger(__name__).setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        with patch("fcntl.lockf") as mock_lockf:
            t1 = Thread(
                target=pacstall.__main__.lock,
                args=(Namespace(command=command), logging.getLogger(__name__)),
            )
            t2 = Thread(
                target=pacstall.__main__.lock,
                args=(Namespace(command=command), logging.getLogger(__name__)),
            )
            t1.start()
            t2.start()
            t1.join()
            t2.join()
>           mock_lockf.assert_called_once()

tests/test_locking.py:50:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <MagicMock name='lockf' id='139855192848512'>

    def assert_called_once(self):
        """assert that the mock was called only once.
        """
        if not self.call_count == 1:
            msg = ("Expected '%s' to have been called once. Called %s times.%s"
                   % (self._mock_name or 'mock',
                      self.call_count,
                      self._calls_repr()))
>           raise AssertionError(msg)
E           AssertionError: Expected 'lockf' to have been called once. Called 2 times.
E           Calls: [call(<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/var/lock/pacstall.lock' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>, 6),
E            call(<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/var/lock/pacstall.lock' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>, 6)].

/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/mock.py:892: AssertionError
---------------------------------------------------------- Captured log call -----------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG    tests.test_locking:__main__.py:50 Lock acquired
DEBUG    tests.test_locking:__main__.py:50 Lock acquired
___________________________________________ TestLockingCommands.test_if_lock_is_called[repo] ___________________________________________

self = <tests.test_locking.TestLockingCommands object at 0x7f3293171df0>, command = 'repo'
monkeypatch = <_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch object at 0x7f3293171130>

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("command", ["install", "remove", "upgrade", "repo"])
    def test_if_lock_is_called(self, command: str, monkeypatch: pytest.MonkeyPatch):
        logging.getLogger(__name__).setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        with patch("fcntl.lockf") as mock_lockf:
            t1 = Thread(
                target=pacstall.__main__.lock,
                args=(Namespace(command=command), logging.getLogger(__name__)),
            )
            t2 = Thread(
                target=pacstall.__main__.lock,
                args=(Namespace(command=command), logging.getLogger(__name__)),
            )
            t1.start()
            t2.start()
            t1.join()
            t2.join()
>           mock_lockf.assert_called_once()

tests/test_locking.py:50:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <MagicMock name='lockf' id='139855192855024'>

    def assert_called_once(self):
        """assert that the mock was called only once.
        """
        if not self.call_count == 1:
            msg = ("Expected '%s' to have been called once. Called %s times.%s"
                   % (self._mock_name or 'mock',
                      self.call_count,
                      self._calls_repr()))
>           raise AssertionError(msg)
E           AssertionError: Expected 'lockf' to have been called once. Called 2 times.
E           Calls: [call(<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/var/lock/pacstall.lock' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>, 6),
E            call(<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/var/lock/pacstall.lock' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>, 6)].

/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/mock.py:892: AssertionError
---------------------------------------------------------- Captured log call -----------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG    tests.test_locking:__main__.py:50 Lock acquired
DEBUG    tests.test_locking:__main__.py:50 Lock acquired
======================================================= short test summary info ========================================================
FAILED tests/test_locking.py::TestLockingCommands::test_if_lock_is_called[install] - AssertionError: Expected 'lockf' to have been ca...
FAILED tests/test_locking.py::TestLockingCommands::test_if_lock_is_called[remove] - AssertionError: Expected 'lockf' to have been cal...
FAILED tests/test_locking.py::TestLockingCommands::test_if_lock_is_called[upgrade] - AssertionError: Expected 'lockf' to have been ca...
FAILED tests/test_locking.py::TestLockingCommands::test_if_lock_is_called[repo] - AssertionError: Expected 'lockf' to have been calle...
========================================================== 4 failed in 1.24s ===========================================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code depends on the behavior of `lockf` raising an `OSError` to modify its control flow -- but you mocked out `lockf`, so it doesn't raise an `OSError`.  In effect your `patch` has modified the behavior of the code so that the lock will always "succeed", which breaks the very thing you're trying to test.

You could add a `side_effect` to your mocked `lockf` so that it more accurately simulates the real `lockf`, but checking its `call_count` still wouldn't be useful, because it will still get *called* twice.

A more useful way to test whether your locking works, IMO, would be to leave `lockf` alone, and pass a `Mock` object as `log` (rather than a real logger), so you can inspect the mock logger's calls and verify that both `log.debug("Lock acquired")` and `log.warn("Pacstall is already running another instance")` happen.

Something along the lines of:

```
log = Mock()

threads = [
    Thread(
        target=pacstall.__main__.lock,
        args=(Namespace(command=command), log),
    ) for _ in range(2)  # or however many
]
for t in threads:
    t.start()
for t in threads:
    t.join()

assert log.debug.call_count == 1  # exactly one successful lock
assert log.warn.call_count > 0    # all other locks should fail
```

Comment: Note that your original test will pass IFF you've only called the function under test exactly once before you check `assert_called_once`.  Not hard to bring that about by introducing threading bugs, but it doesn't mean your test is "working" in the sense of actually verifying anything useful about the code under test.

Comment: `log.debug` still ends up getting called twice

Test: https://sourceb.in/v3rH5vsR38
Test output: https://sourceb.in/msGhVnx1yU

Comment: Could be that your locking doesn't actually work as expected then.  Might want to read http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/locking.html -- there's a note in there specifically about how `lockf` works with multithreading!

Comment: This is a good example of how integration testing can catch things that you miss when you mock everything out -- a mocked version of `lockf` might cause your test to pass, but the actual code would be broken in production because the mocked version was simulating what you *want* `lockf` to do rather than what it *actually* does.  :)